# DispatchQueue.main.async invoked before DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async completed

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I've searched all threading swift 4 on the internet, and it's all like I run it on the code below:

```
var ads = [Ads]()

    func viewDidLoad() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            requestAds()//set self.ads from API and need 1-5 second to response

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.ads = getAds()
                print(self.ads.count) //always 0 because this code run before request completed
                self.adsTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

But all the code runs like not using DispatchQueue like this:

```
requestAds()
self.ads = getPromos()
print(self.ads.count)
self.promoTableView.reloadData()
```

this is requestAds() :

```
func requestAds() {
        let adsProvider = AdsDataService.instance.adsProvider
            adsProvider.request(.allAds, completion: { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let response):
                    print(response.debugDescription)
                    guard let reqAds = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Ads].self, from: response.data) as [Ads] else {
                        print("Can't decode json")
                        return}
                    self.ads = reqAds
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            })
    }
```

and my getAds():

```
func getAds() → [Ads] {
        requestAds()
        return ads
    }
```

It's work when I use delay 6 second (because I can't determine server time response) with this code `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 6.0, execute: code)` from server run code but i think this is the wrong way to implement this.

Anyone have same problem with me? or can help me please? Thank you!

Comment: You need to show the implementation of `requestAds` and `getAds`.

Comment: Okay @rmaddy I've added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set up response time upfront because it's undetermined. Time of server response depends on many circumstances like internet connection, server capacity, etc.

When downloading data from server you must wait until request is completed. I suggest to read more about working with APIs [here](https://grokswift.com/completion-handlers-in-swift/).

Try something like this:

```
var ads = [Ads]()

func viewDidLoad() {
    requestAds { [weak self] (ads) in
        self?.ads = ads
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.adsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func requestAds(completion: ([Ads], Error?) -> ()) {
    let adsProvider = AdsDataService.instance.adsProvider
    adsProvider.request(.allAds) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            guard let reqAds = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Ads].self, from: response.data) as [Ads] else {
                completion([], nil)
                return
            }
            completion(reqAds, nil)
        case .failure(let error):
            completion([], error)
        }
    }
}
```

Key points here are:

- request must have its exit point
- updating UI always has to be in main thread

We use threads to perform multiple operations concurrently, not for waiting for response from server. You can learn about threading from [Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [GCD intro post](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/understanding-threads-in-ios-5b8d7ab16f09).

Comment: Thank you @krlb working nicely, but i still confuse why DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {} not works

Comment: I updated my answer. I encourage you to read some GCD guides and blog posts to learn more about threading. Those two I mentioned above are sufficient to grasp basic knowledge about it.